# C++ Template function chagneable return type

Tags: c++, function, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I have the template struct

```
template <class T>
struct Vector2
{
    T x, y;
};
```

with the following function overloading the + operator

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
Vector2 operator+(const Vector2<T1>& v1, const Vector2<T2>& v2) 
{
    auto x = v1.x + v2.x;
    auto y = v1.y + v2.y;
    Vector2 result{ x, y };
    return result;
}
```

I get the error `argument list for class template "Vector2" is missing`, which I understand why as the return type doesnt supply a type for the template. My issue is I want the return type to change. If both arguments are Vector2 then the return type should be a Vector2. However, if one of the arguments is a Vector2, the return type should be promoted to a Vector2.

I attempted to use auto so that when I create the variable result, it would be converted correctly and the Vector2 wouldnt need a template argument. I know this should work as

```
Vector2 vectorInt = { 3, 2 };

Vector2 vectorDouble = { 1.4,4.4 };
```

both work correctly. The main issue is the return type on the function itself.

I understand I am probably not doing things right as I am curretly new to learning C++ from from my knowledge in other languages.

What I want to know is, is this even possible and if so, how?

Comment: *If both arguments are Vector2 then the return type should be a Vector2* - `Vector2` is a template `Vector2<T>` is a type. *I attempted to use auto so that when I create the variable result, it would be converted correctly and the Vector2 wouldnt need a template argument.* I dont see auto I guess you meant [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)?

Comment: @Ch3steR Yes I understand that the code I supplied wint work and why. The return type needs to be Vector2<something> but I need to determine what <something> is. The auto is used in the function definition as x and y.

Comment: Does the type `something`  in `Vector<something>` would be `T1 + T2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> Vector2 vectorInt = { 3, 2 };
> Vector2 vectorDouble = { 1.4,4.4 };
```

This constructions use [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). The compiler determines template arguments from types of provided initializers.

But there is no way for the compiler to find out template arguments from function declaration or definition. You can use `auto` return type instead:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator+(const Vector2<T1>& v1, const Vector2<T2>& v2) 
{
    auto x = v1.x + v2.x;
    auto y = v1.y + v2.y;
    return Vector2{ x, y };
};
```

But that might not be sufficient if you want to check the return type in constraint templates.So, You can be more verbose by trailing return types:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto operator+(const Vector2<T1>& v1, const Vector2<T2>& v2)
    -> Vector2<decltype(v1.x + v2.x)>
{
    auto x = v1.x + v2.x;
    auto y = v1.y + v2.y;
    return { x, y };
};
```

Or use the old style return type:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
Vector2<decltype(std::declval<T1>() + std::declval<T2>())>
operator+(const Vector2<T1>& v1, const Vector2<T2>& v2)
{
    auto x = v1.x + v2.x;
    auto y = v1.y + v2.y;
    return { x, y };
};
```

In the above snippets you can replace the `decltype(...)` expressions with `std::common_type_t<T1,T2>` as well. But I prefer the `decltype` version for accuracy.